# Empty command output

Tags: bash

I am doing some bash scripting and would like to know how to recognize empty output or a specific string output when running a command in the bash script.

Example - If I perform a ping to google.com and due to no connectivity I get the message "No route to host", I would like the program to echo "You have done a boo boo".

What I have tried:

```
if [[ "$(ping -c 1 -n -q $address | grep -q 'ping: sendto: No route to 
host')" > /dev/null ]]; 
then echo " Your server is up and working, please proceed to the next 
step"
elif [-n "$(ping -c 1 -n -q $address | grep -q 'ping: sendto: No route 
to host')" == *java* ];
then echo "Your server is down, please fix this issue"
else 
echo "No response"
fi
```

Also, looked at other methods of achieving this but couldn't find a working solution.

Comment: Pipes connect one program's stdout to the next's stdin. Error messages aren't on stdout, they're on stderr.

Comment: and btw, I'd really suggest testing for the bad-configuration case with the `ip route` command, not `ping`. Right now, your code will fail if the OP is running it with a locale/translation settings for anything other than English.

Comment: you can also do it like this
`if (nc -z google.com 80) then
 echo "working"
else
 echo "not working"
fi`

Comment: @yausername That seemed to work, thank you :))

Comment: `if nc -z google.com 80; then ...` is a less-pointlessly-inefficient version of the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exit status of `grep`.  `grep` exits 0 if it has a match.

```
if ! ping -c 1 -n -q $address 2>&1 | grep -q 'ping: sendto: No route to host' > /dev/null
then
    echo " Your server is up and working, please proceed to the next step"
fi
```

Comment: (Also, grepping for an error message is innately fault-prone when that error message is coming from a translation table written for humans. You don't know which locale someone will be running your script in -- if your `No route to host` in printed in anything but English, this `grep` won't catch it).

Comment: btw, you still have a stray `)"` left over from the OP's original code.

Comment: I would normally check for the exit code of `ping` itself, but I think it's not specific enough.

Comment: Agreed, it's not -- that's why the better approach is to use a different tool to just test the routing table, rather than to try to abuse `ping` for the purpose. `iproute2` has a subcommand that's specifically intended for the task at hand.